# Sed move line from n° 40 to 39 position

Tags: sed

I have a text file,of 100 lines,i need to move line 40 to line 39(refer to position)
How to do this with sed?
I tried

```
sed '40 m 39' file
```

and

```
sed '40,39m' file
```

but give me error.
Thanks

Comment: I believe this matches the already asked question [SED: Move multiple lines to the end of a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433652/sed-move-multiple-lines-to-the-end-of-a-text-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
seq 1 43 | sed -e '39{h;d};40{p;g}' | tail -n 8
```

Output:

```
36
37
38
40
39
41
42
43
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ sed -e '39N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\
\1/' file
```

Comment: Sorry but doesn't work

Comment: Give error sed: -e expression #1, char 23: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @elbarna: sorry, my typo, if you have GNU sed, try `sed -e '39N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/' file`